# wordpress strangely translates field

Tags: wordpress, translation, qtranslate

I have a Wordpress website with a custom post type that uses custom fields. I have a multilanguage setup with German and English translations. I use the following plugins to get the multilanguage-fuctionality:

- Advanced Custom Fields: qTranslate
- Advanced Custom Fields
- qTranslate slug
- qTranslate-X

On one of my pages I want to display the custom field named `Titel`. I use this php code: `<?php _e(get_field( 'Titel', false, false ));?>`

The weird thing now is that both the English and German version of this field contain the string `Blue`. However, on the German version of the page, this string gets translated to the German version of `Blue` which is `Blau`. But I do not want this to be translated (that's why I entered `Blue` also in the German version of the field). I would assume that simply the string `Blue` is then also displayed in the German version. I already spent one hour to find out where/how the string gets translated, but to no avail.

Any help to identify why/how the string gets translated is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `_e()` function is a wordpress built in [translation function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/). I replaced it with a simple `echo` and now the string does not get translated anymore.